# How to store information across a database with python kivy

Tags: python, json, database, kivy, apk

I am trying to make an app and am currently working on the log in page/sign up page. But I ran into an issue, I can't get information to save to a database of any sort. I've tried to use MySQL along with other big databases like that, but it's very hard and can't seem to get it to work. I also tried to use the kivy JsonStorage, but it won't save when I make the Apk for my phone. If anyone knows how I can get one of these to work I would greatly appreciate it.

This is my code.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.lang import Builder
stored_data = JsonStore("user_info.json")
stored_data.store_load()
Builder.load_file('user_info.json')


class FloatInput(TextInput):`your text`
    input_filter = 'float'

class LimitInput(FloatInput):
    def on_text(self, instance, value):
        if len(self.text) > 8:
            self.text = self.text[0:8]

class login_screen_sign_up(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(login_screen_sign_up, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = FloatLayout()

        "Input Username here :"
        #username input section
        self.login_prompt = Label(text=stored_data.get('Beckett')['password'], size_hint=(0.3, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.6})
        self.add_widget(self.login_prompt)
        self.login_info_un = TextInput(size_hint=(0.3, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.8})
        self.add_widget(self.login_info_un)

        #password input section
        self.password_prompt = Label(text="Input Password here :", size_hint=(0.3, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.6, 'y': 0.6})
        self.add_widget(self.password_prompt)
        self.login_info_pass = TextInput(size_hint=(0.3, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.6, 'y': 0.8})
        self.add_widget(self.login_info_pass)

        #password confirm section
        self.password_prompt_confirm = Label(text="Confirm Password here :", size_hint=(0.3, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.2})
        self.add_widget(self.password_prompt_confirm)
        self.login_info_pass_confirm = TextInput(size_hint=(0.3, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.4})
        self.add_widget(self.login_info_pass_confirm)

        self.button = Button(text="Sign Up", font_size=30,size_hint=(0.3, 0.1), pos_hint={'x': 0.6, 'y': 0.2})
        self.button.bind(on_press = self.click_me)
        self.add_widget(self.button)

    def click_me(self, instance):
        if len(self.login_info_un.text) > 0 and len(self.login_info_pass.text) > 0 and len(self.login_info_pass_confirm.text) > 0:
            global username_taken
            username_taken = False
            for x in stored_data:
                if x == self.login_info_un.text:
                    print('This username is already taken.')
                    username_taken = True
                else:
                    username_taken = False
            if username_taken == True:
                pass
            else:
                if self.login_info_pass.text != self.login_info_pass_confirm.text:
                    print('Passwords do not match.')
                else:
                    stored_data.put(self.login_info_un.text,     password=str(self.login_info_pass.text))
                    stored_data.store_sync()
```

I keep trying this, and it works when I try it online, but when I transfer it to my phone using buildozer, the json storage does not save, and my app crashes.

Comment: can you show any errror message (in question, not in comments)? Did you try to use `/full/path/to/user_info.json` ? It may need to write in special folder for data.

Comment: maybe your problem is [How to give permission to kivy to read and write to android storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173741/how-to-give-permission-to-kivy-to-read-and-write-to-android-storage)

Comment: if you want to use `database` then you may need to use `SQLite`. For other databases you may need to use external computer with database.BTW: if you tried use MySQL then show code in question. Maybe you need only small change in this code - but we can't see it.

Comment: Alrighty, I got the problem solved, so I can run the app on my phone without it breaking.  The data was transferred successfully, so my phone can run the json storage information and use it in my app. But now I have run into the problem where when I try to upload new information to the json storage and save it across all devices, it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page - and add all information, code, error message, etc.